# How to drop the duplicate column in glue job. As glue is creating duplicate column

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have created the glue job and its creating duplicate column once I run the crawler on transformed file .How to drop the duplicate column in it

I have know there is DropNullFields function but it will drop the null field not duplicate coulmn.

What is the way to drop the duplicate column? and stored in csv

Here is code

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "sample", table_name = "test", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

dfc = datasource0.relationalize("root", "s3://testing/")

for df_name in dfc.keys():
    m_df = dfc.select(df_name)
    dropNullfields = DropNullFields.apply(frame = m_df)
    datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = DropNullFields , 
connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://sample/" + 
df_name +"/"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")


job.commit()
```

Comment: Which column is it? Where does this duplicate column come from?

Comment: The root table occurs 3 duplicated column as fname,lname,userid

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.dropFields()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-DropFields.html) function. Example:

```
droppedFields = dropNullfields.drop_fields(paths=["lname", "userid"])
```

Comment: Thank you!!! How to automatize this in the upcoming glue job